# How do I represent a canvas, which is a grid width x height?

Tags: python

So, I am trying to create a python file to read a text file. And the first line that I have is 25 25, and I want to create a canvas which is a grid width x height or 25 25 using list of lists. The following is what I have so far to read to file.

```
print ("***Welcome to my Drawing Viewer Application.***")
print ("This application displays a drawing stored in a text file!")
link = input ("Please, enter the path and name of your file containing a drawing OR X to exit: ")
data = open (link, "r")
print (data.read())
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: `cavans_constructor(map(int, data.read().split()))`?

Comment: print ("***Welcome to my Drawing Viewer Application.***")
print ("This application displays a drawing stored in a text file!")
link = input ("Please, enter the path and name of your file containing a drawing OR X to exit: ")
data = open (link, 'r')
firstLine = data.readline()
x,y = firstLine.split(" ")
x = int(x)
y = int(y)

#By doing this I now have x as 25 and y as 25, i just dont know to create a canvas using these number. The output should look like this. http://www.sfu.ca/~alavergn/120/Assignments/Assn_5/Sample_Run_1.txt

Answer (score 0):

So now that you send me the assigment maybe I could help you..
So the assigment is telling me that you need to build a text file that is constructed so that the python program can read it..

The assigment says that the program needs to read the x and y coordinates we can help with the **open() function**

I will use the examples that are given in the assigment link to make the `house.txt` file.

"house.txt"

```
25 25

3 11

4 10 

4 12

5 9

5 13

6 8

6 14

7 7

7 15

8 6

8 16

9 5
```

every line has its x and y coordinates.

use

```
file_read = open("house.txt", "r")
coordinates = file_read.readline()
x, y = coordinates.split(" ", 1)
print(x)
print(y)

file_read.close()
```

and the output is

```
25
13
```

then you can use the variables to draw on the canvas..

Good luck I helped the most as I can, because the instructions were unclear..